# Area of polygons wrong after intersection using gDifference in R

Tags: r, polygon, spatial

In R  I performed an analysis on a set of X, Y coordinates producing a Voronoi diagram, and I then created a border.  Here I intersect the diagram and the border, and attempt to get the area of the resulting polygons.  The areas for the interior "hole" polys are correct, but the edge polygons appear to maintain their original exaggerated size.  A link to my data is here:

https://drive.google.com/a/ruths.ai/file/d/0B8QG4cbDqH0UaGM2VkkxZHZkZTA/edit?usp=sharing

Code illustrating the problem is here:

```
# Read in shapefiles. 
# Files are located at: 
# https://drive.google.com/a/ruths.ai/file/d/0B8QG4cbDqH0UaGM2VkkxZHZkZTA/edit?usp=sharing

require(sp)
require(rgeos)
SPDF <- readShapeSpatial("SPDF.shp")
SpP <- readShapeSpatial("SpP.shp")

# Examine plots
plot(SPDF)
SPDF@polygons[[337]]@area # Too large; want it cut off
SPDF@polygons[[339]]@area # Hole poly; area correct
gArea(SPDF[339,]) # Provides same area
gArea(SPDF[337,]) # Still provide wrong answer for problem 
                  # poly # 337

# Merge polys using gDifference
D <- gDifference(SpP, SPDF, byid = TRUE)
plot(D) 

# Seems to work, but areas now have a couple of problems.
# I pick apart D using the plotOrder slot to separate
# polys that are holes versus those that are not, allowing
# me to get the correct area for "hole" polys, but the
# edge polygons are still not correct, maintaining their
# area estimates from the original SPDF data frame.

areas <- vector()
for (i in 337:339){ # 337 = exterior poly, 338 and 339 are holes
   po <- D@polygons[[i]]@plotOrder

   if (max(po) == 2) {
      areas[i] <- D@polygons[[i]]@Polygons[[2]]@area 
   } else {
      areas[i] <- D@polygons[[i]]@area
   }
}

areas

# How does one get the right areas for the edges that should be cut 
# off by the intersection?
```

Comment: The `r-sig-geo` mailing list is still the best place for this question. The `rgeos` package author *lives* on that list. And you should always include the `require( sp )` etc package dependencies to get your example to run.

Comment: And you should name the contributed package rather than saying "in R". This is pretty clearly NOT part of base R or any of the recommended packages.

Comment: There may well be other problems involved, but you should at least be aware (for reasons I won't get into here) that extracting the `@area` slot's value is not a reliable way to retrieve areas of `SpatialPolygons` objects. Instead, use `rgeos::gArea()`

Comment: Josh, note that I used gArea() and I get the same areas.  I noticed this comment in previous threads.

Comment: These are certainly useful.  I edited the question to address these comments.

Answer (score 0):

I should have used gIntersection instead of gDifference.  For some reason that I still do not understand, the plot after using gDifference seemed correct, which was the main reason for the confusion.